# Discord.js: interaction has already been acknowledged. Discord Buttons

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, poker

I'm trying to make a Poker command for my Discord bot, and I want to implement turn system with Discord buttons. The command for now is:

1. Someone uses the command
2. The bot sends an embed with a button to join
3. If join is pressed the player element gets pushed into players array
4. If start match is clicked, the bot sends cards in dm
5. Then the bot asks each player if what they want to do in order
6. If the player chooses, the bot crashes and send me this error: `DiscordAPIError: Interaction has already been acknowledged.`

I don't know what is causing the problem. Here's code:

```
const players = [new Player(interaction.user.id, interaction.user.username)];

const hasJoined = [interaction.user];

const playerRow = new Discord.MessageActionRow().addComponents(
    new Discord.MessageButton().setCustomId("join").setLabel("Join").setStyle("SUCCESS"),
    new Discord.MessageButton().setCustomId("start").setLabel("Start Game").setStyle("SUCCESS")
);

const playerEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle(`${interaction.user.username} started a game of Poker Texas hold'em! \nClick the button if you wanna join!`)
.setAuthor({ name: `${interaction.user.username}`, iconURL: interaction.user.displayAvatarURL({ format: "png"})})
.setDescription(`**players:** \n${codeLine(players.map(a => a.name).join("\n"))}`)

interaction.reply({ embeds: [playerEmbed], components: [playerRow] });

const collector =  interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ time: 90000 });

collector.on("collect", async (i) => {

    await i.deferUpdate();

    if (i.customId == "join") {

        //if (hasJoined.includes(i.user)) return i.editReply(`You are already in game ${i.user}!`);

        players.push(new Player(i.user.id, i.user.username));
        hasJoined.push(i.user);
    
        playerEmbed.setDescription(`**Players:** \n${codeLine(hasJoined.map(a => a.username).join("\n"))}`);

        interaction.editReply({ embeds: [playerEmbed], components: [playerRow] });

        if (hasJoined.length == 8) playerRow.components[0].setDisabled(true);
    }

    if (i.customId == "start") collector.stop();
});

collector.on("end", async () => {

    for (let i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {

        const rcard1 = chance.pickone(deck);
        deck.splice(deck.indexOf(rcard1), 1);
        const rcard2 = chance.pickone(deck);
        deck.splice(deck.indexOf(rcard2), 1);
        
        players[i].card1 = rcard1;
        players[i].card2 = rcard2;

        client.users.fetch(players[i].id).then((user) => {
            user.send(`here you are ${players[i].name}! These are your cards: ${players[i].card1.emoji} ${players[i].card2.emoji}.`);
        });
    }

    const matchRow = new Discord.MessageActionRow().addComponents(
        new Discord.MessageButton().setCustomId("stand").setLabel("Stand").setStyle("SECONDARY"),
        new Discord.MessageButton().setCustomId("double").setLabel("Double").setStyle("SECONDARY"),
        new Discord.MessageButton().setCustomId("fold").setLabel("Fold").setStyle("DANGER")
    );

    const matchEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("**Texas hold'em!**")
    .setDescription(`The Small Blind is ${codeLine(players[0].name)} and they bet ${codeLine(bet)} bananas!
    The Large Blind is ${codeLine(players[1].name)} and they double! So ${codeLine(bet * 2)} bananas!`);

    await interaction.editReply({ embeds: [matchEmbed], components: [matchRow] });

    for (let i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {

        const playerFilter = (pInt) => { return pInt.user.id == players[i].id}
        const matchCollector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ playerFilter, time: 90000 });
        
        matchCollector.on("collect", async (int) => {

            await int.deferUpdate();

            if (int.customId == "fold") {

                matchEmbed.setDescription(`${codeLine(players[i].name)} folded!`);

                players.splice(players[i], 1);

            }

            int.editReply({ embeds: [matchEmbed], components: [matchRow], });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: CustomID should be a real custom ID, otherwise you'll have that kind of errors. IDs should be unique.

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand what you meant, I made them all different, so I don't get it xD

Answer (score 2):

You should add an function that diagnoses discord api errors. Add this anywhere on your "index.js" file.

```js
process.on("unhandledRejection", async (err) => {
  console.error("Unhandled Promise Rejection:\n", err);
});
process.on("uncaughtException", async (err) => {
  console.error("Uncaught Promise Exception:\n", err);
});
process.on("uncaughtExceptionMonitor", async (err) => {
  console.error("Uncaught Promise Exception (Monitor):\n", err);
});
process.on("multipleResolves", async (type, promise, reason) => {
  console.error("Multiple Resolves:\n", type, promise, reason);
});
```

Comment: thanks, this events help me to catch discord.js api errors

Answer (score 0):

Your `int` object that comes in your `matchCollector` is a [ButtonInteraction](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/ButtonInteraction). Thus, you can't edit a reply, because you don't have a reply. Instead, if you want to edit the message where is located the Button, you need to use the [ButtonInteraction#update](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/ButtonInteraction?scrollTo=update) method:

```js
int.update({ embeds: [matchEmbed], components: [matchRow] });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're deferring the **update** of the interaction, you should instead defer the  **reply** of the interaction

```
matchCollector.on("collect", async (int) => {
    await int.deferReply();

    if (int.customId == "fold") {
        matchEmbed.setDescription(`${codeLine(players[i].name)} folded!`);
        players.splice(players[i], 1);
    }

    int.editReply({ embeds: [matchEmbed], components: [matchRow], });
});
```